# Create object in database through socket

Tags: scala, sockets, playframework

In my socket I receive object which I should add to my database if it doesn't exists, here is my code but the problem is that nothing is added to database (the method create works fine):

```
  def receive = {
    case result: Result =>
      sessionService.findById(result.id).flatMap {
        case Some(session) =>
          Future.successful(out ! Json.toJson("exists"))
        case None =>
          val session = Session(
            Option(java.util.UUID.randomUUID),
            java.util.UUID.randomUUID,
            java.util.UUID.randomUUID,
            resultItem.versionId,
            java.util.UUID.randomUUID,
            "text",
            "text",
            null,
            null,
            Option(result.scores),
            null)
          sessionService.create(session).map {
            case Right(_id) =>
              println(Json.toJson(Json.obj("_id" -> _id)))
            case Left(error) =>
              println(Json.toJson("message" -> error))
          }
      }
  }
```

UPDATE:

here is the create method:

```
  def create(session: Session): Future[Either[String, UUID]] = {
    println("here")
    collection.insert(session).map {
      case result if result.ok == true => Right(session._id.get)
      case result => Left(result.writeErrors(0).errmsg)
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no bug in the code you've given. Check that `findById` is being called, and working. Then check that `create` is being called.

Comment: findById is called but create no. The println don't show anything I tried to recall findById instead of calling create and it's worked I don't know what's the matter with the call of the create method

Comment: Effectively the create method is called but nothing is added can you please check the update

Comment: is `here` printed? What is `collection.insert` returning?

Comment: yes here is printed and the method returns the object if it's added or error if it doesn't

Comment: I found the problem, thank you very much for your help !!!! I had to put None instead of null in the creation of the object